# Double geometric sum convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

I am trying to understand a proof where the following sum:

$\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=t}^{\infty} r(X_t Y_t)(1-\lambda)\lambda^{n-1}$

where $\lambda \in (0,1)$

Is rewritten to:

$\sum_{t=1}^{\infty} r(X_t Y_t)\lambda^{t-1}$

How is this possible?

I know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda^{n-1} = \frac{1}{1-\lambda}$ since it is a geometric series and $\lambda < 1$, but then I would expect the sum to be:

$\sum_{t=1}^{\infty} r(X_t Y_t)$

since $\frac{1-\lambda}{1-\lambda} = 1$

Comment: The inner summation starts at $n=t$, not $n=1$; thus you can write it as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lambda^{t+n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \lambda^{t-1}\lambda^n$, and the $\lambda^{t-1}$ term here can be moved out of the sum.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thank you, I see it now! I mixed up some subscripts